# Detect two or more UIButtons being pressed at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, storyboard, uitouch

I have three `UIButtons` on a storyboard.

What is the most straightforward way to detect when:

- two of the `UIButtons` are being pressed at the same time?

or

- three of the `UIButtons` are being pressed at the same time?

Comment: don't know if it makes any sense, i found it interesting..

Comment: If the button is highlighted, it's currently being pressed e.g. `if button.highlighted && button2.highlighted`

Comment: and you could check that code inside a function connected with either one of the buttons, so when one button is clicked, it checks if the other one(s) are clicked too

Comment: May be it right way to use an instance of UITapGestureRecognizer with 3 touches and then in delegate  - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:  check touches location with CGRectContainsPoint..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be easy if you use Touch Down Event and Touch Up Event.

**Touch Down:**
When the finger is pressed

**Touch Up:**
When the finger is lifted.

So on Touch Down set the variable that that specific button is touched and on the Touch Up Event check whether both the Buttons are currently being Touched. Like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var Button_1_Pressed: Int = 0;
    var Button_2_Pressed: Int = 0;

    @IBAction func Button_1_Down(sender: AnyObject) {
        Button_1_Pressed = 1;
    }

    @IBAction func Button_2_Down(sender: AnyObject) {
        Button_2_Pressed = 1;
    }

    @IBAction func Button_1_Up(sender: AnyObject) {
        if (Button_1_Pressed == 1 && Button_2_Pressed == 1){
            println("1- Both Pressed at same time");
        }
        Button_1_Pressed = 0;
    }

    @IBAction func Button_2_Up(sender: AnyObject) {
        if (Button_1_Pressed == 1 && Button_2_Pressed == 1){
            println("2- Both Pressed at same time");
        }
        Button_2_Pressed = 0;
    }
}
```

You can set these @IBAction using your XCode interface builder by pressing CTRL key on button and then selecting the event and drag to your swift file. The above code only implements 2 buttons but it would give you an idea for the rest of buttons.

If you are using iOS Simulator you can detect two touches using Option key.

Comment: Thanks. This gives me the idea.